# Storing glut color in variable

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Is there any way to store a glut color in a variable, like instead of doing this:
`glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`
being able to do this:

```
glColor white = glColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glColor3f(white);
```

which in turn creates much more readable code

Comment: Neither the data type `glColor` nor the function `glColor` exists. Store the color in an array.

Comment: @Rabbid76, it was an attempt to write psuedo code, I knew none of those existed, I just used them to help my explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to store the color in an array and set the color with  [`glColor3fv`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml):

```c
float white[3] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
```

```c
glColor3fv(white);
```